# Least-squares problem with Householder transformation

Tags: numerical-methods, numerical-linear-algebra, least-squares

We need to find a linear function $f(x)=a_1x+a_0$ such that $\sum_{i=1}^4(f(x_i)-y_i)^2$ is minimal. $x_1=-2,x_2=-1,x_3=0,x_4=1,$ and $y_1=1,y_2=2,y_3=0,y_4=1$.

So, if I am right, I need to solve the least-squares problem for
$$A=\begin{bmatrix}1 & -2\\1 & -1\\ 1&0\\1&1\end{bmatrix},b=\begin{bmatrix}1\\2\\0\\1\end{bmatrix}$$ and our "$x$"$=\begin{bmatrix}a_0\\a_1\end{bmatrix}$.

Is it correct so far?

I'm asking because the results I get on paper are questionable.

Comment: There is a typo in the last row and second column of $A$. It should be $1$.

Comment: Thanks, I've corrected my mistakes.

Comment: Then you apply the least squares formula $x=(A^TA)^{-1}A^Tb$...

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you are correct so far.

The title of your post suggests that you want to use a Householder transformation to solve the problem.  An example of how to do that is at ["Example: Solving a Least Squares Problem using Householder transformations."](http://www.math.sjsu.edu/~foster/m143m/least_squares_via_Householder.pdf)